# Which floors house these company offices?

Tags: riddle

There is a 10 storey office building in UK. It has no basement.

> If you enter the bulding from the street, you will find the offices of
>   Groupon Enterprises on that floor.
>
> Nicot Enterprises occupies the very top floor.
>
> One floor above the Groupon offices are the company offices of Secret
>   World.

So

> The offices of Seth Reed company are on the ______d floor.
>
> The offices of Siracuse Ventures are on the ______th floor.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I see this

> Nico **t En** terprises occupies the very top floor. **TENTH**
>  The offices of Se **th Ree** d company are on the ______d floor. **THIRD**
>  The offices of Siracu **se Ven** tures are on the ______th floor. **SEVENTH**
>  Thanks to @Hexomino's comment,
>  Group **on E** nterprises. **FIRST**
>  Secre **t Wo** rld. **SECOND**
>  **EDIT:** So, for UK floors, we could minus 1 from each
>  Making: 
>  Group **on E** nterprises. 1 - 1 = **GROUND**
>  Secre **t Wo** rld. 2 -1 = **FIRST**
>  The offices of Se **th Ree** d company are on the ______d floor. 3 - 1 = **SECOND**
>  The offices of Siracu **se Ven** tures are on the ______th floor. 7 - 1 = **SIXTH**
>  Nico **t En** terprises occupies the very top floor. 10 - 1 = **NINTH**
>  **Final Thought**
>  If the above is not the correct solution, then after pondering this dilemma for a while, the only solution I can come up with is this:
>  The building that said offices are in, is adjacent to the one we're viewing it from. However, the building we are in is one floor lower in elevation than one with the offices. We would then be looking at the Ground floor unit from our first floor unit.

Comment: This must be it because you have rot13(Tebhc(BA R)agrecevfrf ba sybbe BAR naq Frper(G JB)eyq ba sybbe GJB.)

Comment: If this is right, the question should've specified the building is in the US, not the UK. These are US floor numbers.

Comment: Good comment @msh210

Comment: Ah, that's better. Though _for a building in the UK_ there is something unsatisfactory about it :-).

Comment: Now you talking @MacGyver88

Comment: The subtraction is not clued in the puzzle in any way that I can tell, which makes it rather arbitrary.

Comment: I heard [these guys](https://vermillion.com/investor-overview/#presentations) are having a really hard time finding a suitable office..

Comment: Is it really consistently British convention to start with ground and then count up? I know when I hear similar stuff about the US like this, it almost never turns out to be true.

Comment: sorry, what do y'all mean about US and UK numbers?

Answer (score 4):

Note that

> Groupon starts the same as GROUND floor; and Nicot starts the same as NINTH (the top floor from a British convention in a 10 storey building).

So

> SEth Reed is on the SEcond floor, and SIracuse is on the SIxth floor.

Comment: You ninjaed me by 13 seconds, but only because I took time to point out what seems to be an error in the question :-).

Comment: It’s a good catch by you, for sure, @GarethMcCaughan!

Comment: Then why isnt Secret World on the SEcond floor? It is not an error

Comment: Apparently not a good catch, then...

Comment: Oh well, worth a shot!

Answer (score 4):

**Dubious answer**

(Dubious because if it's right then I think there is an error in the question.)

It looks to me as if

> we are looking for floor numbers whose English names have as many initial characters as possible in common with the company name. Ground/Groupon, Ninth/Nicot.

BUT

> if so then it seems like there's an error, because the floor about the ground floor is the *first* floor, not the *second* (cf. Second/Secret).

Anyway, if this is correct then

> Seth Reed will be on the **se**cond floor, and Siracuse Ventures on the **Si**xth.

Comment: Great minds think alike! fantastic answer, +1

Comment: Answer may be right but look closely even the so called error is not an error.

Comment: In the UK (where this office building is located), the floor numbering is G, 1, 2, 3, ...